# How to identify if application is killed

Tags: android, service, alarm

How to identify if application is killed so that we can restart service by putting some alarm manager in Android at a specific interval of time ?

Answer (score 1):

`Service` is automatically restarted after process is killed if you return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand`. You don't need `AlarmManager` for that.

Comment: MaciejGorski - Will this even work with some applications like "Advance Task Killer" ?

Comment: Yes I did the same, I am returning START_STICKY in every service on "onStartCommand" also crashing purposefully, but after crash, i don't see service getting restarted by itself, is there any events we need to put other than that to invoke service ?

Comment: @user1223035 Frankly I don't know how it would work with tasks killers. They are useless unless you have applications that do wrong things: e.g. use (too much) CPU when in background. Users should also be aware of disabling them for certain applications. About crashing: I would not expect restart if application crashes (uncaught exception).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean, but you could implement the `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` methods in your code then use a Toast in them eg.

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        Toast.makeText(this, "activity stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "activity destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

that should give you an indication when your activity goes through the life cycle. I should point out that android handles when your application is "killed"

Comment: Lunchbox - I believe it only gives information about activity, i want to know event when application crashes or gets killed